# Connecting to command prompt to generate keys by GNupg in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, command-prompt, gnupg

How to write query in PostgreSQL to connect to Commnad Prompt?
I want to generate keys in GNUpg in PostgreSQL query itself by calling command prompt. 
Are there any predefined functions or procedures for it or do we need to write functions in plpgsql?

Answer (score 3):

by using  `PL/sh`   Procedural Language Handler, we can able to connect postgresql to shell prompt

simple example is

```
 CREATE FUNCTION concat(text, text) RETURNS text AS $$
#!/bin/sh
 echo "$1$2"
$$ LANGUAGE plsh;
```

-- before that as any other language have to add plsh to the working database, 
you can check whether language already in the database by using

```
select * from pg_language;
```

Comment: Ok. Thanx a lot but could you please guide me how to add plsh to my database?